# 501 Method not implemented error while recording Facebook script using JMETER

Tags: jmeter

Unable to record login script for Facebook while doing this with HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder in manual proxy server mode and redirected to [501 Method not implemented.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5i17I.png)

Comment: Please have a read here: [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) as this is way to vague. What have you done? What are you trying to do? What didn't work? And it looks like a home work question, to be honest....

Answer (score 0):

My expectation is that you need to import JMeter's self-signed certificate into your browser prior to starting recording.

1. Locate `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` file (it's being generated in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation when you start JMeter proxy)
2. Add it to your browser. The steps differ from browser to browser, check your browser documentation for details on how to do it
3. Repeat recording. This time it should work.

References:

- [Apache JMeter proxy Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)
- [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) (pay attention to the following chapters:

  - **HTTPS recording and certificates**
  - **Installing the JMeter CA certificate for HTTPS recording**
- [Recording HTTPS Traffic with JMeter's Proxy Server](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-https-traffic-jmeters-proxy-server)